# The print statement separates two equations by | .I am unable to understand it's real function

Tags: python

`print(2%2|1)`

This returns 1 but I am unable to understand the function of the | operator. Does it compare both equations? Is this the only function?

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR in Python (and many other languages).  The effect of `x | 1` is to set the low bit of the number, turning even numbers into the next higher odd number.

Answer (score 5):

According to Python's operator precedence rules, the expression is equivalent to:

```
(2 % 2) | 1
```

And that's equivalent to:

```
0 | 1
```

That evaluates to `1`. And to be clear, `|` is the *bitwise or* operator.

Comment: @VedantBhosale please consider accepting the most useful answer, just click on the check mark to its left. See this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on Óscar López' answer: When using bitwise operators in python, the binary representation of the arguments is compared.

A different example may help understanding the logic:

```
17|3
```

arguments converted to binary format:

```
17:  10001
3:      11
```

In case of the bitwise or (|) a comparison of the two binary terms is done, which returns a 1 if any of the two terms has a 1 at the particular position and 0 otherwise:

```
17:  10001
3:      11
res: 10011
```

In this case, the comparison yields 10011, which converted back to decimal is 19.